# What is "на проводах" in the context of the army?

Tags: перевод

I've seen this phrase recently:
на проводах в армию

I don't know what it means. Is it literal or an idiom, or...?

[Example](http://tltgorod.ru/news/theme-29/news-47620/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word [`Проводы`](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B) means 'going away party', 'farewell', and may be translated as 'send-off'. 
As [@Nikolay Ershov](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/4560/nikolay-ershov) mentioned, Проводы is any farewell party for someone going away, not just to the army.

```
Проводы мужа в командировку.
Проводы детства.
```

In your example it matches another word — `Провод` (a wire), so it might confuse you. This word is spelled the same, but has different meaning and sounding (homograph?). In speech you can distinguish them by accent.

```
прОвод, проводА (a wire, wires)
прОводы (send-off)
на проводАх (on wires)
на прОводах (at send-off party)
```

<sup>(The stress is on capital letters.)</sup>

Comment: Intriguingly, no-one has mentioned the verb "провожать" (imperf), "проводить" (perf) - to see off, from which "прОводы" stems.

Comment: "прОвод"/"проводА" also stem from "проводить" (to pass [electric current]).

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 2 meanings:

1. *На прОводах* - kinda *on farewell party* - in this context *farewell to military service*
2. *На проводАх* (plural) or *на прОводе* - means *on wires* or just *connected*, *on line*

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't means something related to wire (провод). Проводы means party (usually with family and some friends) when a young man is going to army. So "на проводах" means "at the party".

It's WRONG: You should read it as проводЫ with stress on last syllable.
See comments below.

Your example: student stabbed his brother at the party.

Comment: You are absolutely wrong about the stress, **the stress is on the 1st syllable**: прОводы, на прОводах: [http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/проводы](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/проводы).

Comment: Also, проводы is any farewell party for someone going away, not just to the army.

Comment: Stress falls to the first syllable, -1

Comment: «...проводы́ with stress on last syllable» — весьма любопытно. Говорите, вы харьковчанин? Если не секрет, коренной? И просклоняйте (с ударением), пожалуйста, по падежам; если считаете возможным, то и в единственном числе тоже.